# "Games creation" vs "Creation of games" and similar

Tags: prepositions

I'm updating my CV and I want to list some software tools along with what have I used each tool for. However, I'm having some trouble with the following choices:

- "Video games creation" vs "Creation of video games" vs "Creating video games".
- "Vector graphics edition" vs "Edition of vector graphics" vs "Editing vector graphics".
- "Audio recording and edition" vs "Recording and edition of audio" vs "Recording and editing audio" .

Which one sounds better or is more correct? Any rules or hints on when to use each option (specially between the first and second option of each case; the use of "of" is always complicated)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Any hints on the third cases, with the gerunds?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if the structures are identical. "Secretary of the Department" doesn't look equal than "Creation of video games" to me. Here, we're using of to connect a verb with a noun, while in the linked question it connects two nouns.

Comment: video game creation, audio recording and editing, vector graphics editing. The language of resumes goes even further than normal speech in stringing attributes before the head noun of a compound, but these three sound perfectly normal.

Comment: I could easily see myself choosing 'video games creation' in some contexts, 'the creation of video games' in others, and 'creating video games' in yet others. None is wrong per se, and choice of style is partly subjective but partly informed by context. And in many cases, one variant is as good as another. // I'd definitely choose 'editing' rather than 'edition' (though again this is not strictly incorrect) whichever variant I opted for, as @KarlG suggests. //// As I pointed out, the structures correspond in form. The ...

Comment: underlying question in both posts is 'Should I use an attributive noun or an of-construction?'

Comment: The reason CVs use this technique is 1) by the time you get to the head noun, which is some task you hope to get paid for, that noun is narrowly defined, and 2) such long compounds sound "official" even if you're making them up on the spot.

Comment: Stating it more absolutely than Edwin Ashworth did, "edition" isn't used that way in English. "Edition" is used mostly to mean a version or specific release of a work--the director's edition of a DVD, the 2018 edition of the Old Farmer's Almanac, the international edition of the Herald Tribune. To refer to the act of editing of a work, "editing" is usually used, or else it's used as a verb instead of a noun: "digital editing", "edited video graphics".